# PhantomJS javascript wait until function complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phantomjs, wait

I have a problem with a PhantomJS script. The script gets a JSON encoded string from a web page and does other things with it. The script:

```
var address = address;
var amount = 0;

function changeAmount()
{
   var page=require('webpage').create();
   page.open (address, function(){
     //parse json, set amount to something (usually 4)
     amount = 4;
  });
}

changeAmount();
console.log(amount); //prints 0

//Do stuff with amount

phantom.exit(); //amount not changed yet.
```

How can I check if the changeAmount function is finished before going forward? Timeout is not possible since I don't know the time it takes to process the changeAmount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page.open()` is an inherently asynchronous function. The only reliable way to do this is to use callbacks in the PhantomJS script:

```
var address = address;

function changeAmount(callback)
{
   var page = require('webpage').create();
   page.open (address, function(){
     //parse json, set amount to something (usually 4)
     var amount = 4;
     callback(amount);
  });
}
```

You can even go as far as passing `amount` into that callback to remove the global variable.

After that, you will need to write your script using that callback pattern.

```
changeAmount(function(amount){
    console.log(amount);

    //Do stuff with amount

    phantom.exit();
});
```

---

Furthermore, you probably shouldn't create a new `page` every time you call `changeAmount()` (if you do this repeatedly). You can reuse the same `page`. If you think that creating a new page gives you a fresh environment to work in, then you're mistaken. It is just like a new tab. It will use the same session as all the other pages that you have created.

If you do this often, this will lead to a memory leak, because you're not closing the previously opened pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback, like so:

```
function changeAmount(callback) {
    var page=require('webpage').create();
    page.open (address, function () {
        //parse json, set amount to something (usually 4)
        amount = 4;
        callback();
    });
}

changeAmount(function () {
    // This function runs when callback() (above) is reached
    console.log(amount);

    //Do stuff with amount

    phantom.exit();
});
```

And if you're not using the `amount` variable elsewhere, you could eliminate it by passing it as an argument to the callback:

```
changeAmount(function (amount) {
```

and then

```
callback(amount); // or callback(4);
```